# Array of array values

Tags: php, arrays

I am unable to get `stores` and `store_id` from this array. Please help me, how to get `stores` and `store_id` from this array of arrays?

```
Array
 (
    [group_data] => Uni_Banner_Model_Bannergroup Object
    (
        [_eventPrefix:protected] => core_abstract
        [_eventObject:protected] => object
        [_resourceName:protected] => banner/bannergroup
        [_resource:protected] => 
        [_resourceCollectionName:protected] => banner/bannergroup_collection
        [_cacheTag:protected] => 
        [_dataSaveAllowed:protected] => 1 
        [_isObjectNew:protected] => 
        [_data:protected] => Array 
            (
                [group_id] => 4
                [group_name] => list banner1
                [group_code] => list_banner1
                [banner_width] => 320
                [banner_height] => 460
                [animation_type] => 1
                [banner_effects] => Fade/Appear
                [pre_banner_effects] => 
                [banner_ids] => 1
                [show_title] => 0
                [show_content] => 0
                [link_target] => 0
                [status] => 1
                [created_time] => 2015-03-04 14:47:40
                [update_time] => 2015-03-04 14:47:40 
            )
        [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 1
        [_origData:protected] => Array 
            (
                [group_id] => 4
                [group_name] => list banner1
                [group_code] => list_banner1
                [banner_width] => 320
                [banner_height] => 460
                [animation_type] => 1
                [banner_effects] => Fade/Appear
                [pre_banner_effects] => 
                [banner_ids] => 1
                [show_title] => 0
                [show_content] => 0
                [link_target] => 0
                [status] => 1
                [created_time] => 2015-03-04 14:47:40
                [update_time] => 2015-03-04 14:47:40
             )
        [_idFieldName:protected] => group_id
        [_isDeleted:protected] =>
        [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array 
            ( 
            )
        [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array 
            (
             ) 
    )
 [banner_data] => Array
     (
        [0] => Uni_Banner_Model_Banner Object 
            (
                [_eventPrefix:protected] => core_abstract
                [_eventObject:protected] => object
                [_resourceName:protected] => banner/banner
                [_resource:protected] => 
                [_resourceCollectionName:protected] => banner/banner_collection 
                [_cacheTag:protected] => 
                [_dataSaveAllowed:protected] => 1 
                [_isObjectNew:protected] => 
                [_data:protected] => Array
                     (
                        [banner_id] => 1 
                        [title] => List Banner 
                        [filename] => custom/banners/File-1440417903.jpg 
                        [link] => http://localhost/magentonew/french/ 
                        [banner_content] => 
                        [stores] => 4,6 
                        [storeviews] => 
                        [status] => 1 
                        [sort_order] => 0 
                        [banner_type] => 0 
                        [created_time] => 2015-08-25 16:44:46 
                        [update_time] => 2015-08-25 16:44:46 
                        [store_id] => Array 
                            (
                                [0] => 4
                                [1] => 6 
                            )
                     )
                [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 1
                [_origData:protected] => Array 
                    (
                        [banner_id] => 1
                        [title] => List Banner
                        [filename] => custom/banners/File-1440417903.jpg
                        [link] => http://localhost/magentonew/french/
                        [banner_content] => 
                        [stores] => 4,6 
                        [storeviews] => 
                        [status] => 1 
                        [sort_order] => 0 
                        [banner_type] => 0 
                        [created_time] => 2015-08-25 16:44:46 
                        [update_time] => 2015-08-25 16:44:46 
                        [store_id] => Array 
                            ( 
                                [0] => 4
                                [1] => 6 
                            )
                     )
                [_idFieldName:protected] => banner_id
                [_isDeleted:protected] => 
                [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array 
                    ( 
                    )
                [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array 
                    (
                    )
            )
    )
)
```

Comment: Please, format your questions accordingly, your code is unreadable.

Comment: Dat one-liner. That should be many lines, potentially a newline after each "arrow".

Comment: I just edited it, indented. Your `store_id` data is well buried inside an inception of arrays and objects.

Comment: Try to print your array between `<pre></pre>` tags.

Comment: If `$a` receives it, you'll access it like `$a['banner_data']->_data['stores']` or `$a['banner_data']->_data['store_id'][0]`, assuming it's inside a class that extends this mess, since object properties are protected.

Comment: how are you coming up with this array? I think this is where the root of your problem lies.

Comment: I agree with the first comment, this entire question needs to be formatted much differently.

Comment: Also, there are **no code trials** of yours, we didn't see any efforts to achieve it. Where is your code?

Comment: @gopinadh WE NEED FEEDBACK!

Comment: i have tried in different ways but i am not getting the store_id values, at last iapproached Stack exchange. So sorry for the code i have pasted,                                                                                                          $bannerGroupCode = $this->getBannerGroupCode();
$data = $this->getDataByGroupCode($bannerGroupCode,Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code get the data for this specific array and objects. You should really use some getter methods for the objects and iterate the array(s) properly.

```
$arr = your array
$arr['banner_data'][0]->_data['stores'] and
$arr['banner_data'][0]->_data['store_id'][0]
$arr['banner_data'][0]->_data['store_id'][1]
```

Comment: I'm commenting it out of good will, it does **not** mean your answer is wrong. Please, don't encourage bad questions with answers, as the author may become satisfied without the obligation of proper writing it or giving any feedback on the subject, polluting the knowledge base.

Comment: Hi Adi,  this is my array,                                                  $bannerGroupCode = $this->getBannerGroupCode();
$data = $this->getDataByGroupCode($bannerGroupCode,Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId());